# Neovim - Colorsheme not displaying correctly

Tags: neovim

I want to use `modus-vivendi` as my color scheme.
If the colorscheme is set in the `colors.lua`, it it does not display correctly, but if it is set directly from `nvim` (with a different color scheme set by default), it has no problem. You can see here:

[image: img]

I leave here my [config](https://github.com/enrico223/.config/tree/main/nvim) if that can be of any use.

Can you also point me at some resources on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Output of `nvim -v`:

```
NVIM v0.8.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by builduser

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"
```

Comment: How is it displaying incorrectly (your pic is actually pretty similar with modus-vivendi's demo pic). Also are you on a 256 color terminal (what's the output of `echo $TERM`)?

Comment: They are very different left part is correct, the right one is the problem. I'm updating the question so that it is clearer. Output of `echo $TERM` is `xterm-kitty`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Try [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) to reduce your config to the minimal amount needed to reproduce the problem, then [edit] and include the minimal steps directly in your question.

Comment: Problem remains even with the minimal config

Comment: Hmm try having `export TERM=xterm-256color`. I'm using vim on tmux on kitty and it works fine; still I cant help you with neovim though

Comment: Your input on TERM gave me an idea, and I found the problem. I don't remember why, but I had `termguicolors = false` in my `set.lua`. Setting it to `true` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the option `termguicolors` was set to `false`.
Setting it to `true` solves the issue.